# How can i add data to database in laravel

Tags: php

We i had a separate file for adding data it is working fine with the below things. but when i am using that with in a table and it's not working. can anyone please help with these. how add the data to it, and also help me with datepicker and checkbox post i have requested for help. Thank you in advance

**Code**

```
<tr>
<form action="storeself" method="post">
<td><input type="date" name="assigndate"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="topic"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="activity"></td>
<td><select class="form-control" name="respon">
  <option>--SELECT--</option>
  <option >Hementh</option>
  <option >Vijay</option>
  <option >Usha</option>
  <option >Arun </option>
  <option >Yohith </option>
</select></td>
<td><select class="form-control" name="support">
  <option>--SELECT--</option>
  <option >Hementh</option>
  <option >Vijay</option>
  <option >Usha</option>
  <option >Arun </option>
  <option >Yohith </option>
</select></td>
<td><select class="form-control" name="priority">
  <option>--SELECT--</option>
  <option >High</option>
  <option >Medium</option>
  <option >Low</option>
</select></td>
<td><input type="date" name="targetdate"></td>
<td><select class="form-control" name="status">
  <option>--SELECT--</option>
  <option >To be Started</option>
  <option >In Progress</option>
  <option >Completed</option>
</select></td>
<td><input type="date" name="compledate" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="remarks"></td>
<td><input type="int" name="targerweek"></td>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
<td><button input type="submit" name="submit"value="submit">ADD</button>
  </form>
</tr>
```

**routes**

```
 Route::get('selfadd','selfctrl@addself');
 Route::get('selftask', 'selfctrl@selflist');
 Route::post('storeself','selfctrl@insert');
 Route::any('selfdele/{id}', 'selfctrl@destroy');
```

**controller**

```
class selfctrl extends Controller
{
   public function addself(){
     return view('forms.selftask.list');
   }


   public function insert(Request $request){

    DB::table("selflist")->insert([

      "assigndate"=>$_POST["assigndate"],
      "topic"=>$_POST["topic"],
      "activity"=>$_POST["activity"],
      "respon"=>$_POST["respon"],
      "support"=>$_POST["support"],
      "priority"=>$_POST["priority"],
      "targetdate"=>$_POST["targetdate"],
      "status"=>$_POST["status"],
      "compledate"=>$_POST["compledate"],
      "remarks"=>$_POST["remarks"],
      "targerweek"=>$_POST["targerweek"]
    ]);
    return "Hello";
  }
  public function selflist(){
   $users = DB::table('selflist')->get();
   return view('forms.selftask.list')->with('users',$users);
  }
  public function destroy($id)
  {
    DB::table('selflist')->Where('id',$id)->delete();
    return redirect('selftask')->with('success','deleted successfully');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.
First of all, You need to call post parameters via

```
$request->input('name');
```

The other thing is, You should **never** use table names in controllers, You should use Models for queries.

Comment: But when i add that content a separate file it's working without calling request, but the problem comes when i am accessing that in a table and adding under that